# Autocomplete suggestions on angular ui grid filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

I am stuck on a task where I have to implement autocomplete suggestion list on filter input box for different columns. I am using angular ui-grid - v3.0.0, I did search for solutions but didn't find any good solution. I found an example for Kendo-UI https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/filtering/autocomplete-suggestions-by-current-grid-filter, I want similar functionality please provide a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

The AngularJS ui-select is a good component for handling lists.

it has many functionalities like filtering, auto-complete, grouping and so on.

Go to this link for more information:

[AngularJS ui-select](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/)

**Custom header in ui-grid**

In the 'filterHeaderTemplate' You can customize headers as you wish and put

an auto-complete component inside it.

Go to this link for creating custom header:

[custom header in ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef)

Comment: Actually, i want to know the way how to implement this with ui-grid on filter.

Comment: create a custom header and add this component inside it. I add more details to my answer.